# Get values from Multidimensional nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I am trying to get `fulltext` values from this json file on this [Link](http://www.marketingarabs.com/php.php)

I am getting only top of the array how can I get all values from all arrays even the nested ones

```
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json_output);
foreach($json_output['results'] as $item) {
    echo '<br/>'. $item['fulltext'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Id try looking at spl in PHP, it gives you useful iterator classes including ones specially for complex arrays - http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: Also check http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html - i found this very useful when i first had to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

another approach would be to

1) convert your json to xml (json -> php array -> xml) - you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19987539/2596503) recursive function:

```
function to_xml(SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data)
{   
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {   
        if (is_array($value))
        {   
            $new_object = $object->addChild($key);
            to_xml($new_object, $value);
        }   
        else
        {   
            $object->addChild($key, $value);
        }   
    }   
}   

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rootTag/>');
to_xml($xml, $my_array);
```

2) query the xml with XPath to fetch the collection of data you need, for example

```
$titles = $xml->xpath('//@fulltext');
```

Utilising XPath you can easily fetch data also by complex constraints, check out [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
foreach($json_output['results'] AS $result) { 
     foreach($result['printouts']['Covers topic'] AS $topic) { 
      echo "<ul><li>".$topic['fulltext']."</li></ul>"; 
     } 
     echo "<br/>".$result['fulltext']; 
    }
```

Thanks for your help guys